# Асинхронно дополнить элементы массива

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, xmlhttprequest

Есть массив объектов. Каждый из объектов нужно дополнить аттрибутами, получаемыми из асинхронной функции (HTTP-запрос). Если какой-то из запросов выдал ошибку, его можно повторить, но не более одного раза. Как это делается в async.js?

До:

```
[{
url: example.com/123,
param1: 123,
param2: 456
}]
```

После:

```
[{
url: example.com/123,
param1: 123,
param2: 456,
additional_data: <html>...</html>
}]
```

Comment: что за async.js?

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async